# Unreal Engine freezes while importing a FBX file

Tags: unreal-engine5, fbx, unreal

## Issue

- I've downloaded any character from [Mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/#/?page=1&type=Character)
- Those files normally 1MB and in a few seconds you can import them
- Trying to import to the project
- First, I see a progress bar, then basically no action on the editor, freezes
- Waited minutes
- I can only close the editor from the task-manager
- I'm using the [Unreal Editor 5.3.1](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/unreal-engine-5.3-release-notes/) version

This wasn't always the case, it started randomly. I can't go further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

Here is how I was able to solve it:

While importing the [FBX file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBX):

- It will open the file explorer at the beginning
- And in that window, at the bottom right, there is a dropdown list, it is set to **all files** by default which didn’t work → Sometimes freezes → Sometimes not
- Choose “FBX Skeletal Meshes (*.fbx)” from the dropdown list of file types
- If you import it like that, it imports very well

I hope it will help someone.

[image]